# Is the *Updating OpenGL version to 4.1 (LWJGL)* question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

This question: [**Updating OpenGL version to 4.1 (LWJGL)**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69198/updating-opengl-version-to-4-1-lwjgl)

The question has an open bounty, but is it on-topic?

---

> **Note:** The question has been closed, and the bounty refunded.

Answer (score 9):

No, the question is not on-topic.

The code is incomplete, the shaders do not function, and there are a number of deprecated method calls that the asker knows are used. Further, the asker knows there are serious concerns about whether the initialization routine even works, given the deprecated methods use: *The problem is, I don't have access to a compatibility profile, only the core 4.1 profile, so all of the deprecated calls I was making need to be removed.*

Putting this all together, the code is not in a state that is ready for review. We are not sure it works as it is, we know that it will need to be rewritten before it is complete.

This, in turn, means that an answer like: "Your code is great, looks good", is not possible. In general, the expectation is there that code presented for code review should be answerable with "Looks Good" (the code works, no significant edge cases, good style, etc.). That is not possible here, and the asker knows that... which results in the logical close reason:

- This question is asking for a review of code that has not yet been written.

and is off-topic.

The question should be closed, and the bounty refunded.

If the question can be restructured in a way that:

- simplifies the actual problems to the component parts
- says: *here's my old code, what is the replacement function (non deprecated) in 4.1 version*

then it may be on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Comment: post on main is now closed.